# How can I keep only one summary at a time in an event file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a situation where I only want to store a single tensor at a time. IIUC, the FileWriter appends summaries to the existing event file. Right now, every time I want to write a summary, I do the following in a class init:

```
self.WRITER = tf.summary.FileWriter(self.LOGDIR, 
                                    max_queue=1, 
                                    flush_secs=9999999)
```

and in a class method:

```
summary = self.SESSION.run(tf.summary.tensor_summary('frame', 
                                                     image_tensor))
self.WRITER.add_summary(summary)
self.WRITER.flush()
self.WRITER.close()
```

With `.close()`, it only writes once. Without `.close()`, it appends to the event file. With `self.WRITER.reopen()` at the beginning of the method, it adds new event files. I would like to have a single event file that is overwritten every time.

Is there any way to do this through TensorFlow, or do I need to remove the old file manually and create a new summary at each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to refresh the file with the last event as I see but you can use

```
os.remove("path/to/file")
```

on each iteration.